# Searching through an ArrayList

Tags: java

> Implement a method
>
> ```
> public void search (String searchString) { }
> ```
>
> to iterate through the notes ArrayList until it
>   finds a note that contains the searchString.
>   It should then print either the item found or
>   the message "String not found".

So far, I have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * A class to maintain an arbitrarily long list of notes.
 * Notes are numbered for external reference by a human user.
 * In this version, note numbers start at 0.
 * 
 * @author David J. Barnes and Michael Kolling.
 * @version 2008.03.30
 */
public class Notebook
{
    // Storage for an arbitrary number of notes.
    private ArrayList<String> notes;

    /**
     * Perform any initialization that is required for the
     * notebook.
     */
    public Notebook()
    {
        notes = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * Store a new note into the notebook.
     * @param note The note to be stored.
     */
    public void storeNote(String note)
    {
        notes.add(note);
    }

    /**
     * @return The number of notes currently in the notebook.
     */
    public int numberOfNotes()
    {
        return notes.size();
    }

    /**
     * Show a note.
     * @param noteNumber The number of the note to be shown.
     */
    public void showNote(int noteNumber)
    {
        if(noteNumber < 0) {
            // This is not a valid note number, so do nothing.
            System.out.println("invalid index given");
        }
        else if(noteNumber < numberOfNotes()) {
            // This is a valid note number, so we can print it.
            System.out.println(notes.get(noteNumber));
        }
        else {
             System.out.println("there are fewer items in the notebook");
            // This is not a valid note number, so do nothing.
        }
    }

    public void removeNote(int noteNumber)
    {
        if(noteNumber < 0) {
            // This is not a valid note number, so do nothing.
             System.out.println("invalid index given");
        }
        else if(noteNumber < numberOfNotes()) {
            // This is a valid note number.
            notes.remove(noteNumber);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("there are fewer items in the notebook");
            // This is not a valid note number, so do nothing.
        }
    }

    /* Edit note.
     * I tried to improve the formatting of the code below, but I'm completely
     * unable to figure out how on earth anything of that should make sense
     * and therefore the indentation is completely without any meaning.
     */
    public void search (String searchString)
    { 
        for each notes in ArrayList {    
            if notes = searchString;        
                System.out.println("String found"); + searchString        
                return    end 
            }
        if}
        System.out.println("String not found");
    }
}
```

But it is not working, and I am not able to work it out.

Comment: Does "if notes ArrayList (searchString <= 0)" even compile?

Comment: Generally compilers give errors explaining why they won't compile code. Reading a basic Java control structures tutorial like Mark Byers suggested in his answer is a start, but you should also be paying attention to what specific errors your compiler is telling you about.

Comment: Looks like C# or Java. Or at least, that's what the compiler would be expecting to get.

Comment: I've got no idea if you still look at stackoverflow using that account. If you do, please have a look at the question and try to fix the last part of the code.

Answer (score 5):

Several problems:

1. Your `search` method is actually outside the class.
2. The body of your search method makes no sense at all.

If you're counting on the monkeys writing Shakespeare, you'll be waiting a while.

Answer (score 3):

To iterate over the array list, you can use a ['for-each' loop](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html):

```
for (String note: notes) {
    // Do something with note
}
```

This is very basic syntax. Have you seen it before? If not, you should start by reading a very basic tutorial to Java before attempting this homework.

Comment: Since this is Java I'm not sure that would help.

Comment: I didn't notice the generic ArrayList<T> at first, and thought it was C#. ArrayList is not generic in C# - the generic version is just called List<T>.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally you need to look at each item in your ArrayList and test to see if it matches the search condition.  In Pseudocode

```
for each note in notes
{
    if note equals searchString then 
        print "Found " + searchString
        return
    end if
}

print "not found"
```

Given that basic outline, want to take a second stab at coding it in Java?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want to loop over the elements, and for each one check whether it equals the element you are searching for. You can use a for loop or a foreach loop to do the actual iteration.

Answer (score 2):

should you be checking if the whole note matches your searchstring, or if the note contains your searchstring?

i.e. given notes "foobar","baz","spam", should a search on "foo" return "foobar" or not match on anything?

so in pseudocode:

```
for each note in notes
{
     if searchstring in note
     {
           print "Found :"+note
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check this website http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_java/arrays.html it may be useful